# FMT creation by using latex.ltx

Tags: xmltex

I am trying to create the `FMT` file by using the `latex.ltx` for the following procedures.

1. Copy `latex.ltx` file from the base directory to my local
   working directory.
2. Rename this file.
3. I Load my orginal source files for the following commands before the
   `\dump` command.

   `\input xmltex.tex
   \input Sample.cfg
   \input Sample.xmt
   \LoadClass{article}
   \dump
   \endinput`

I am compailing the ltx file for the following command like `latex -ini filename.ltx`

First i am getting the following error.

```
! LaTeX requires e-TeX.
l.98     {LaTeX requires e-TeX}

?
```

So i comment the those lines from the `ltx` file and try to run the `ltx` file.

```
%   \errmessage
%     {LaTeX requires e-TeX}
%   \expandafter\endinput
```

After comment those lines from the ltx file, i will run the ltx file once again. But i am getting the below mentioned errors.

So, i will change my compilation command `etex -ini filename.ltx`. But the same errors are repeated.

The `.ltx` show the plenty of errors during the compilation process

`\utfthreeuniglyph ... \expandafter {\the \numexpr
                                                  4096*(#1-224)+64*(`

```
! Extra \else.
\unicodechar ...nichar@\number #1\endcsname \else
                                                  \errmessage {Unicode
```

I am unable to fix this error. I place my MWE for your reference.

```
%%Sample.tex%%
\def\xmlfile{sample.xml}
\input xmltex

%%Sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "JATS-journalpublishing1.dtd">
<article>
<front>
<article-meta>
<title-group>
<article-title>The sample title</article-title>
</title-group>
</article-meta>
</front>
<body>
<sec id="j_nanoph-2018-0214_s_001">
<title>Introduction</title>
<p>The <bold>Sample.cfg, Sample.xmt, Sample-entity.sty</bold> files needs to be converted into unreadable format &#x00C1; &#x00E1;.</p>
</body>
</article>

%%Sample.xmt%%

\XMLentity{TeX}{\TeX}
\XMLentity{LaTeX}{\LaTeX}

%%%%Main Root Tag%%%%
\XMLelement{article}%
    {}%
    {\documentclass{article}%
    \begin{document}}%
    {\end{document}}%
%%%%

\XMLelement{bold}{}{\xmlgrab}{\textbf{#1}}


%%%%Front Matter Tags%%%%
\XMLelement{front}{}{}{%
  \date{}
  \maketitle%
}%
%%%%

\XMLelement{article-title}{}{\xmlgrab}{\title{#1}}

\XMLelement{title}{}{\xmlgrab}{\section*{#1}}

\XMLelement{p}{}{}{\par}%
```

Could you please advice how to clear those errors and getting the successful `FMT` creation for the following source files.

Comment: You need to run `etex -ini * filename.ltx` or `pdftex -ini * filename.ltx`, or something like that. The `*` in the command tells `etex` to start in extended mode (that is, with the ε-TeX extensions loaded) so that LaTeX can work properly.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The * etex extended mode is working well. Your answer is incredible. But the below mentioned error is thrown.`xmltex version: 2002/06/25 v1.9 (Exp)

Encoding = utf-8
(C:\Users\latex\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\xmltex\base\xmltex.cfg)

No File: sam.cfg)

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8447 \
        input sample.cfg
?`

Comment: I think the dump files like `\input xmltex.tex
\input sample.cfg
\input sample.xmt
\LoadClass{article}
\dump` could not be dumped properly. If anything wrong in my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any programming language if you are getting an error, simply commenting the error message out of the source without fixing the issue is not likely to solve anything.

Do not copy or edit `latex.ltx`

Look at `pdfxmltex.ini` which is in a location such as

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/xmltex/xmltexconfig/xmltex.ini
```

copy that file to a new name in your local area say `myxmltex.ini`

The file is, in total

```
% public domain.
\let\primitivedump=\dump
\let\dump=\relax
\input pdflatex.ini
\let\dump=\primitivedump

% then read jadetex.  pdf output must be set first, since it needs hyperref.
\input xmltex.tex
```

Then if you want to speed things up by pre-loading large packages such as `tikz` you could add

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
```

after the `pdflatex.ini` line.

then make a format with

```
 pdftex --etex --ini myxmltex.ini
```

which you can use as

```
  pdftex \&myxmltex  your-xml-file.xml
```

To preload more of the xmltex internals would require modifying more of the xmltex sources and isn't recommended (or likely to be useful).

The xmltex manual says

> Unfortunately the support for this method of building xmltex (and access
>   to non English hyphenation generally) is not fully designed and totally
>   undocumented.

It has to be asked, are you sure you want to use xmltex? I wrote it a long time ago (It is actually older than XML) before XML tools were widely available. It does sort of work but it is far easier to use XSLT to process the XML documents writing out "normal" TeX documents which you can then process with a normal pdflatex run.

Comment: The above `myxmltex.ini` is not working. The FMT file is not created.  `% public domain.
\let\primitivedump=\dump
\let\dump=\relax
\input pdflatex.ini
\input xmltex
\LoadClass{article}
\let\dump=\primitivedump
% then read jadetex.  pdf output must be set first, since it needs hyperref.` The following errors has been throw `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} l.6 \
     LoadClass{article}`. How its work? Please advice

Comment: How it is work `\dump` and `\primitivedump`. I can't find solution. Please advice on this.